# Trapping system signals in Swift4

Tags: swift, signals

I'm working on a swift project which launches child processes using `Process`.  I want to make sure all these processes are terminated when the parent process is terminated.

I've attempted to do this with Darwin's `signal` method:

```
    let task = Process()
    task.launchPath = "/usr/bin/env"
    task.arguments = [path] + self.args
    task.standardOutput = outputPipe

    outputPipe.fileHandleForReading.waitForDataInBackgroundAndNotify()

    _ = interruptSignal.once {
        if task.isRunning {
            task.interrupt()
        }
    }

    signal(SIGKILL) {signal in
        print("ending with signal: \(signal)")
        interruptSignal.emit()
    }
```

But the closure passed to signal never gets executed.

I'm sure the `SIGKILL` is being sent to the parent process, because when I use the stop button on XCode I see this in the console:

```
Program ended with exit code: 9
```

I have also tried `kill -s KILL` from the command line, and still there is no result.

Is there some step that I'm missing?  For context, this process is running through the XCode testing framework, if it matters.

**edit:** event emitter implementation added per request

```
public class Event<T> {

    ...

    public func emit(_ data:T) {
        for observer in observers {
            observer.action(data)
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: What is `interruptSignal` and where is it defined?

Comment: @MartinR that's an event which is defined as a global variable.  It's an event emitter component implemented elsewhere in the project (details added to post).  Basically calling emit executes the closure supplied to `once` synchronously in the same thread.  The emitter is tested and works consistantly.  A global var was used, because signal is a C function so it only allows globally scoped variables to be accessed.

Comment: Are you aware that SIGKILL *cannot* be caught? See https://developer.apple.com/legacy/library/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man3/signal.3.html.

Comment: No I was not aware of that!  Is there any way to ensure that all child processes will be terminated when the parent process ends?

Comment: man page for signal that Martin R provided no longer works as of feb'19. An alternative that does is https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/System/Conceptual/ManPages_iPhoneOS/man3/signal.3.html